# Handle error page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

for ex: I type the url: localhost:3000/hoasung01 then it throws a message:

```
Unknown action
The action 'hoasung01' could not be found for StaticController
```

And in console:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'hoasung01' could not be found for     StaticController):
```

I spent many hours to research and try some ways:

```
rescue_from AbstractController::ActionNotFound, with: :page_not_found
#(ActionController::RoutingError, ActionController::UnknownController,  ::AbstractController::ActionNotFound, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

protected
def page_not_found
  render 'layouts/404.html', :status => 403, :layout => false
end
```

but it does not render 404.html page. ( I use rails 4.1.5 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In development you are shown a special error page to help you figure out errors. I you want to test that `404` and `500`s work look at this blog post: http://thepugautomatic.com/2014/08/404-with-rails-4/

The section **Verify in development** says t `config/environments/development.rb` and add the following line:

`config.consider_all_requests_local = false`